# i am implementing logic gates in prolog but having this error

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

```
and(A,B) :- A, B.

or(A,_) :- A.
or(_,B) :- B.


error that i am getting is this
```

compiling C:/Users/firoz/OneDrive/Desktop/neww codes/tt.pl for byte code...
C:/Users/firoz/OneDrive/Desktop/neww codes/tt.pl:10: warning: singleton variables [Expr] for do/2
C:/Users/firoz/OneDrive/Desktop/neww codes/tt.pl:11: warning: discontiguous predicate do/3 - clause ignored
C:/Users/firoz/OneDrive/Desktop/neww codes/tt.pl compiled, 11 lines read - 2112 bytes written, 7 ms

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of GNU prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/index.html) ? What book did you read about Prolog (in general)? Please notice that **StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website**

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a comma in this line:

```
do(_,_,Expr):- Expr,!,write(true),nl.
```

Comment: even after that it is also giving same error

Comment: Are you sure you are compilng the same program? You error message states errors involving `do/2` and `Expr` in lines 10-11, but they appear in lines 23 onward in your code snippet.

Comment: yes i am compiling the same code and it shows this

Comment: Both errors go away with this fix. Also in GNU. As you are using Wind-os better restart GNU Prolog.

Comment: Both errors go away with this fix. Also in GNU. As you are using Wind-os better restart GNU Prolog.